# Make reference to a Setting name using a Variable

Tags: c#, variables, application-settings

I have the following expresion which sets a MenuItem name based on a Setings

```
memoryToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[**i**].Text = 
    Convert.ToString(Properties.Settings.Default.**M**1);
```

I would like to use the variable "i" after the "M" to make reference for a group setting named alike.

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I don't agree with marking this question as a duplicate, solely because of the fact that the accepted answer to the linked question needlessly involves reflection (i.e., why make it simple when you can make it complicated), which is really not a good suggestion at all...

Comment: @elgonzo One should look at all the answers, not just the accepted one, just in case there is a better (fsvo) answer available. The most upvoted answer to the question which this is a duplicate of is the same as your answer here.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, i don't know. Of course one should look at the other answers, but it doesn't sit well with me if the first (and accepted) answer in the list is kinda bad, and the actual good answer (while having the most votes) is only 3rd in a list of 4 answers :(

Answer (score 1):

You can access settings properties via an [indexing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.item(v=vs.110).aspx). This indexing operator requires a string with the name of the setting property you wish to access:

```
string propertyName = ... // compose property name string according to your requirements
object propertyValue = Properties.Settings.Default[propertyName];

string stringRepresentationOfValue = Convert.ToString(propertyValue);

memoryToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[i].Text = stringRepresentationOfValue;
```

Comment: It will return `object`, so cast is required.

Comment: @apocalypse No, casting does not really work here. The types of the objects returned can be different, that's the whole reason why return type is Object. Notice `Convert.ToString` in the code of the question? But i will add this to my answer to make it more complete...

Comment: I wanted to say cast is required if he want to access type specific memebers :>

Comment: Thanks It does what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

1) go to line: `Properties.Settings.Default`
2) set your mouse cursor at `Default` property
3) hit `F12` key
4) you will see auto-generated code with your settings
5) you can now understand how it works by reading the code